# A function gives empty string in script but gives the correct return value in console

Tags: javascript, asciidoctor

I want to create a simple webpage that takes asciidoctor file and converts it to html using `asciidoctor.js`. For testing I'm opening the webpage directly form my local storage. The webpage includes the following input element:

```html
<input type="file" id="file-selector" onchange="readDoc(this)" accept=".txt, .ad, .doc, .asciidoc, .asc"> </input>
```

The javascript of the page:

```js
const processor = Asciidoctor({ runtime: { platform: 'browser' } })
var adoc = '';
function readDoc(selector) {/*ready to work*/
    var fileList = selector.files;
    var theFile = fileList[0]
    var reader = new FileReader();
    adoc = '';
    reader.onload = function(loadedEvent) {
        adoc = loadedEvent.target.result
    }
    reader.readAsText(theFile);
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = processor.convert(adoc);
}
```

The weird thing is: Inside `readDoc` function, `processor.convert` returns empty string and the `content` element becomes empty after uploading a file. However, when I execute that same line in console, the converter returns the correct html of the document and the element updates! (I made all variables global to be able to execute that line from console) What's happening?

Comment: @ScottyJamison readDoc() is called after I upload a file, I think after the page is completely loaded.

Comment: You need to move the last two lines of your function inside the onload callback. Right now, they're executing before the onload callback runs. (this is also why it works when you do these instructions one at a time in the console, you give the browser enough time to finish the onload callback before you type in the next instruction)